# AddThis markup doesn't show up in TinyMCE html editor

Tags: asp.net, html, tinymce, addthis

I have a content management system that I have designed which uses XML files as its basis. Every thing is finished and running great except for the markup for AddThis doesn't show up in the tinymce editor. It also doesn't even appear in the HTML view. This wouldn't be that big of a deal except for if a user edits that section of the page, it deletes the addthis control.

Any ideas?

Here is how the markup is on the page and in the xml file:

```
<div style="float: left; margin-top: 1px; font-family: arial; color: #005396; margin-left: 3px; font-size: medium; margin-right: 200px;">Join Our Mailing List</div>
      <div style="clear: right; float: right;">
        <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 8px; font-family: arial; clear: left; float: left; color: #333333; font-size: large; vertical-align: middle;">Check Out _ Weekly <br /><span style="font-family: arial; color: #005396; font-size: large;">National Polling Summary </span></div>
        <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style" style="float: right; padding-top: 15px;">
          <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
          <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
          <a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
          <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Here it is in the HTML section of tinymce

```
<div style="float: left; margin-top: 1px; font-family: arial; color: #005396; margin-    left: 3px; font-size: medium; margin-right: 200px;">Join Our Mailing List</div>
<div style="clear: right; float: right;">
<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 8px; font-family: arial; clear: left;     float: left; color: #333333; font-size: large; vertical-align: middle;">Check Out _    Weekly <br /><span style="font-family: arial; color: #005396; font-size: large;">National   Polling Summary </span></div>
</div>
```

Here is my tinymce init:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode: "textareas",
    theme: "advanced",
    plugins: "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing: true,
    relative_urls: false,
    editor_deselector : "mceNoEditor",


    // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    // using false to ensure that the default browser settings are used for best Accessibility
    // ACCESSIBILITY SETTINGS
    content_css: "Symba/Styles/CSS/Site.css",        
    // Use browser preferred colors for dialogs.
    browser_preferred_colors: true,
    detect_highcontrast: true,

    // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
    template_external_list_url: "lists/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url: "lists/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url: "lists/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url: "lists/media_list.js",

    // Style formats
    style_formats: [
        { title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b' },
        { title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: { color: '#ff0000'} },
        { title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: { color: '#ff0000'} },
        { title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1' },
        { title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2' },
        { title: 'Table styles' },
        { title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1' }
    ],

    // Replace values for the template plugin
    template_replace_values: {
        username: "Some User",
        staffid: "991234"
    }
});
```

**Update**

Ok I tried adding this to the init function

```
 valid_elements: "*[*]",
 extended_valid_elements: "*[*]"
```

and that brought the div back but I still am not getting the anchor tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FCKEditor and Tinyeditor remove empty elements by default. Try to add empty spaces to your anchors like this:

```
<a class="addthis_button_facebook">&nbsp;</a>           
<a class="addthis_button_twitter">&nbsp;</a>           
<a class="addthis_button_email">&nbsp;</a>           
<a class="addthis_button_compact">&nbsp;</a>


<div style="float: left; margin-top: 1px; font-family: arial; color: #005396; margin-left: 3px; font-size: medium; margin-right: 200px;">Join Our Mailing List</div>
<div style="clear: right; float: right;">
<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 8px; font-family: arial; clear: left; float: left; color: #333333; font-size: large; vertical-align: middle;">Check Out _ Weekly <br />
<span style="font-family: arial; color: #005396; font-size: large;">National Polling Summary </span></div>
<div style="float: right; padding-top: 15px;" class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook">&nbsp;</a>           
<a class="addthis_button_twitter">&nbsp;</a>           
<a class="addthis_button_email">&nbsp;</a>           
<a class="addthis_button_compact">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't put &nbsp; into xml because it isn't well-formed. I will play with it and get back with you

Comment: That did it, the only problem is that it put little dashes and an extra space between the images. Any ideas there?

Comment: Actually is there a way to undo this behavior?

Comment: I finished it by adding the  valid_elements: "*[*]",
 extended_valid_elements: "*[*]" and then only putting the &nbsp; to the last anchor tag.